# Trying to launch old game using wine

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wine

I'm using wine 1.5.11 on Archlinux, and I try to launch this old game :

http://www.cnetfrance.fr/telecharger/waterboy-11006056s.htm?download=1

The problem is that I always get a

```
"Run-time error '13' : Type mismatch"
```

when I try to launch it.

I've tried to switch *oleaut.dll* and *ole32.dll* to "native", and switch to "Windows 98" mode using winecfg, and then I had this error :

```
err:module:import_dll Library ole32.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\games\\WaterBoy\\MSVBVM50.DLL") not found
err:module:import_dll Library OLEAUT32.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\games\\WaterBoy\\MSVBVM50.DLL") not found
err:module:import_dll Library MSVBVM50.DLL (which is needed by L"Z:\\games\\WaterBoy\\WaterBoy.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\games\\WaterBoy\\WaterBoy.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

I've installed vb5runtime using winetricks, but it didn't help.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Wine is to much of a crapshoot for me to bother with.  Its far easier, and much more stable, just to boot to windows.

Comment: @Keltari, if you can afford the bloat, yes. Wine is not crap, most of the time the problems are really license and legal issues created by you know who.

Comment: It's now always microsoft's fault, wine should show a message at least on what to do if the user wants to ignore all the license crap.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `winetricks` from http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks, to install the missing native libraries

```
wget http://winetricks.org/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks 
sh winetricks corefonts vcrun6 vb5run native_oleaut32 vcrun2010 richtx32
```

Some windows will popup for confirmation.